# Apache rewrite url and hide old url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to simplfy an URL but cant find how to do that.

Here is the original URL that exists and works.
https://example.com/s/732kglm

I want to use this different URL for the same content.
https://example.com/info

I can do that in apache with a redirect

```
Redirect permanent /info /s/732kglm
```

Now if I open https://example.com/info I will be redirected to https://example.com/s/732kglm but the browser shows the original URL.

I want to hide tho original URL so that user only sees the simplified URL https://example.com/info

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you using these directives? In `.htaccess`? Or in the server config (virtual host)? Or `<Directory>` container? How is your "original URL" currently being _routed_? What other directives do you have?

Comment: I tried both, but non does hide the old URL /s/732kglm.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an internal redirect. I don't have access to apache to test, but something like the following should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/info$" "/s/732kglm"
```

Comment: If this is being used in `.htaccess` then the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ would need to be removed (ie. `^info$`). However, whether this will work at all depends on how the original URL is currently being handled/routed. `/s/732kglm` does not look like a valid end-point, so this probably requires further rewriting, in which case the application is likely only going to see the originally requested URL, not the rewritten URL (that the application understands), so it's likely just going to result in a 404 since the application does not understand the URL `/info`.

Comment: cont... on the other hand, if `/s/732kglm` ultimately maps to a physical file (perhaps `/s/732kblm.html`) that handles the request directly then this would work OK (but that seems unlikely given the format of the URLs). Either way, it's complete guess work without  knowing more about the application and how the original URLs are routed.

Comment: Apache config does not scale smoothly. It's of the reasons I switched to nginx years ago and never looked back.

Comment: Right now I use .htaccess but I also tried <Directory>. I tried to remove the slash. That does not change anything. Both configuarations will redirect sucessfully to  /s/732kglm. But both also show /s/732kglm in browser address line what I dont want..